# How to merge audio and video file in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to merge an audio file (.wav or .au format) with a video file (.mp4 format).

Please suggest me how to achieve this. I want to merge these file to new .mp4 video file. An ffmpeg command would be very welcome.

Comment: There's a decent article here that might be helpful too... http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/muxing-audio-and-video-with-ffmpeg/

Comment: Simon East's comment's link from web archive - http://web.archive.org/web/20150103030913/https://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/muxing-audio-and-video-with-ffmpeg/

Comment: Same question on SO: [FFMPEG mux video and audio (from another video) - mapping issue - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938581/ffmpeg-mux-video-and-audio-from-another-video-mapping-issue)

Answer (score 695, accepted):

#### Merging video and audio, with audio re-encoding

See this example, taken from [this blog entry](http://crazedmuleproductions.blogspot.com/2005/12/using-ffmpeg-to-combine-audio-and.html) but updated for newer syntax. It should be something to the effect of:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Here, we assume that the video file does not contain any audio stream yet, and that you want to have the same output format (here, MP4) as the input format.

The above command transcodes the audio, since MP4s cannot carry PCM audio streams. You can use any other desired audio codec if you want. See the [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.

If your audio or video stream is longer, you can add the `-shortest` option so that ffmpeg will stop encoding once one file ends.

#### Copying the audio without re-encoding

If your output container can handle (almost) any codec – like MKV – then you can simply copy both audio and video streams:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c copy output.mkv
```

#### Replacing audio stream

If your input video already contains audio, and you want to replace it, you need to tell ffmpeg which audio stream to take:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
```

The [`-map` option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) makes ffmpeg only use the first video stream from the first input and the first audio stream from the second input for the output file.

Comment: I tried it but ffmpeg is freezing while merging

Comment: i don't think mp4 containers can have wav audio streams. Try `ffmpeg -i audio.wav -i video.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mkv output.mkv`

Comment: I am using this and it is replacing the origional audio from the input audio. What if I want to merge input audio with the audio of input video?

Comment: Great, I used ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav \
-c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4 to merge MP3 with Wav file...=> mp4 5 minutes, rendered 30 seconds..Thanks

Comment: About the "Replacing audio stream", will it work even if there is no audio in the video file? And how can I make the audio loop in case it's too short compared to the input video? I've also noticed that if the audio is longer than the video, the output video will be as long as the audio file. Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: Many thanks for the `-strict experimental`, because all the articles and answers I've found before just told me to use `-c:v copy` and it always just gave me an error that `copy` decoder doesn't exist.

Comment: I couldn't get `-map 1:a:0` working to replace the audio stream, despite ensuring that the inputs were in the same order. So, I just removed the audio `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -an output_an.mp4`, then I executed the first option with reencoding and it worked.

Comment: If I know the audio is longer and all I want is 3 seconds of Fade In and Fade Out. Can I do it?

Comment: For what it's worth, the command line used by `youtube-dl` to ask `ffmpeg` to merge a pair of video and audio files is `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mkv`, according to [its source code](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/2020.06.16.1/youtube_dl/postprocessor/ffmpeg.py#L521). The presence or absence of those `-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0` parameters do not seem to make a difference based on my recent attempt, though.

Comment: using -an before -i will ignore the audio stream and -vn before -i will ignore the video stream and I gues it will make it faster telling ffmpeg not to decode unnecessary streams.

Comment: Why would you use `-c:a aac` instead of `-c:a copy`?

Comment: How to actually merge with the existing audio?

Comment: My copy of ffmpeg doesn't like that "output" keyword. Removing it still worked fine.

Answer (score 33):

Since I am not allowed to write comments to the first answer with my reputation, an addendum here, because I had this problem when encoding webms. 
**If your audio stream is for example longer than the video stream**, you have to cut it or otherwise you will have the last video frame as a still image and audio running.

To cut either stream, you can use -ss [hh:mm:ss] -t [ss] before each of the -i "file.ext". 
-ss [...] will define the starting point to cut 
-t [...] will define the length of the segment in seconds 
 
Example:

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:10  -t 5 -i "video.mp4" -ss 0:00:01 -t 5 -i "music.m4a" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y "out.mp4"
```

Example with `shortest`:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -i "music.m4a" -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest "out.mp4"
```

Comment: You can also just use `-shortest` to cut the end.

Answer (score 16):

Open command promt (<kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>). Then go to inside the folder where you have audio and video file. Apply this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "videoFile.mp4" -i "audioFile.mp3" -shortest outPutFile.mp4
```

You will get a new file named `outPutFile.mp4` (a merged file of audio and video)

Comment: It's really not necessary to describe how to use the command line here. It's pretty much implied that users will be able to figure that out. Especially since the asker specified FFmpeg. All the same, the `-shortest` tag is very nifty. Much simpler than in @user136036's answer.

Comment: This will re-encode everything, which is probably not what is wanted.

Comment: http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Comment: 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: You have to add ffmpeg to PATH http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

Comment: if you are inside the same folder where your file lies , need not to add path

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on my mac.  I'm trying to combine an M2V file with a WAV file.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i AudioT.m4a -i VideoT.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy muxed.mp4
```

Comment: its partially working for me, not working for all inputs, some resulting input videos remains same in the output

Comment: Detailed: https://superuser.com/questions/590201/add-audio-to-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

Try using mencoder (Yes it is ffmpeg based, but you never know). I use the `-audiofile` argument. I generally use ffmpeg, though, so take this advice with a pinch of salt.

And, if you use Windows, Mediacoder (not open source anymore sadly) works... its basically a frontend for a lot of gnu encoders and a few non-free ones.

Answer (score 1):

In case one would like to merge audio and video with different length and also to apply *Fade In* and *Fade Out* the following worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i Video001.mp4 -i Audio001.mp3 -af afade=t=in:st=0:d=3,afade=t=out:st=47:d=4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest Output.mp4
```

In my case above the video was of length 51 so I chose *Fade In* of length 3 [Sec] and Fade Out* of ~4 [Sec]. Since fading is applied by a filter it required transcoding of the audio. In the case above I chose `aac` encoding.

The answer is [heavily based on the answer](https://superuser.com/a/277667/95468) of @[PatrickGeorgi](https://superuser.com/users/76365/patrick-georgi).

Answer (score 1):

`-map` can be used to produce an English mashup from two mp4 video sources with varying English and foreign language properties:

- video-sub.mp4 - a foreign video containing English subtitles, but with a foreign audio track
- video-dub.mp4 - a foreign video containing foreign text, but has an English dub audio track

To an English mashup that has English subtitles and an English dub audio track:

```bash
ffmpeg -y \
       -i video-sub.mp4 \
       -i video-dub.mp4 \
       -vcodec copy \
       -acodec copy \
       -map 0:v:0 \
       -map 1:a:0 \
       video-mashup.mp4
```

You'll see that `-vcodec copy` and `-acodec copy` are used so no decompression and recompression will occur. This requires that the source videos, idealistically, are the same format resolution and the same duration.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a Python script to do this, you can try it if you want.
Get it on github:
https://github.com/mmakarov/replicator

Or look at video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Uu1hS3-eQM

> Replicator is a Python script to merge a few video files, transparent
> overlay, text areas with mp3 audio track. Final video will be exact
> same length as your audio track. Lenght of your video will be
> calculated automatically.
>
> I've make this script in a try to merge any video sequence files with
> PNG transparent overlay, adding text areas on video, with mp3 audio
> track. Resulting video file are ready to upload on Youtube or any
> other video hosting services.
>
> You can change it on your taste.
>
> How to use it: 0. Open terminal and enter: git clone
> https://github.com/mmakarov/replicato...
>
> 1. Put your video files to project directory as 'source1.mp4', 'source2.mp4', etc
> 2. Put your PNG transparent image to project directory as 'overlay.png'
> 3. Put your MP3 file to project directory as 'voice.mp3'
> 4. in terminal run: python3 source-to-medium.py (here will be created 'medium.mp4')
> 5. enter your text areas contents if needed ...it takes some time to convert source*.mp4 files to one medium.mp4
> 6. in terminal run: python3 medium-to-fin.py ...it will caltulate final video length dividing voice.mp3.length() / medium.mp4.length() =
>    silent_fin.mp4.length() ...also it will add voice.mp3 to
>    silent_fin.mp4 as audio track
> 7. Finally you've got youtube_ready.mp4 files
>
> Warning: russian comments in sources!