# Merge audio and video using ffmpeg and retain both video and audio voice

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to merge audio and video using ffmpeg. I use following command but it erases my audio from video. I want overlap of audio from both video and audio.

```
ffmpeg-0  -i output312.mp4 -i abc.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0    -y output2.mp4
```

Comment: Similar: https://superuser.com/questions/590201/add-audio-to-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the amerge filter:

`-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2`

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a2stereostereo