# Combine video and audio and loop audio until video ends

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Can you please check this out.

```
 ffmpeg -y -i 21653634-merge.mp4 -i dreamy.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 out.mp4
```

I am trying merge video and audio. It is by the way merging, but what I am trying to achieve is the music should loop until the video ends.

I tried the solution from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1319945), but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as

`ffmpeg -y -i 21653634-merge.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i dreamy.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M out.mp4`

Comment: Hi, tried the command you commented and it's not stopping. frame=  925 fps=5.5 q=-1.0 size=   99584kB time=01:36:17.53 bitrate= 141.2kbits/
frame=  925 fps=5.5 q=-1.0 size=   99840kB time=01:36:34.64 bitrate= 141.1kbits/
s speed=34.5x

Comment: Edited  cmd.....

Comment: Thank you very much! I have lots of questions with ffmpeg. Hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Here's what I am trying to achieve. Is it possible to create this using ffmpeg https://superuser.com/questions/1501075/ffmpeg-image-to-video-with-kenburns-effect cheers!

Comment: Input #1, mp3, from 'assets/music/dreamy.mp3':
  Metadata:
    comment         : Audio recorded by Yout.com
    title           : 6 Second Music (Loopable, Downloadable) for Vine Videos and other Short Videos
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
videos/301432/21653634-final.mp4: Permission denied

I am getting a permission denied in the live server.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways is to use the `concat` format for the input: Create a file called `dreamy.ffconcat`

```
file "dreamy.mp3"
file "dreamy.mp3"
file "dreamy.mp3"
file "dreamy.mp3"
...
```

besides `dreamy.mp3`. It must have enough lines to make sure you have enough repetitions, but it won't hurt if you have much too many.

Now use `ffmpeg -y -i 21653634-merge.mp4 -f concat -i dreamy.ffconcat -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 -shortest out.mp4`

Comment: Thanks, will try this one too.