# How to use ffmpeg to rip audio from mp4 and add it to another

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, multiplexing

I created a video using Final Cut Pro X (10.1.4) and added a commentary using the voiceover feature.  I was surprised to discover that FCPX does not support outputting a file with multiple audio tracks.

I disabled the commentary track and saved the project in 1080p with just the regular audio (main.m4v).

I then re-enabled the commentary and adjusted the regular audio and exported a 720p version with just the commentary track (commentary.m4v).

How do I use ffmpeg to create final.m4v, which would be main.m4v but with the audio track from commentary.m4v as a secondary audio track?

Comment: maybe you could refer to  https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg

Comment: That solution talks about replacing the existing audio or mixing the two audio tracks into one.  I want to rip the audio from one m4v file and add it as a second separate track to an existing m4v.

Comment: ah my bad, I misunderstood the question, you may use this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/317739/how-to-add-an-additional-sound-track-to-an-existing-video if you could compromise with `ffmpeg`-only

Comment: Thanks!  With that example, I got some very interesting results.  I got a m4v that works exactly how I want in VLC, but with quicktime, it doesn't let me pick an audio track and plays both at the same time.  I need to do some research on this, but I am definitely close to what I am after.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [mapping options](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20use%20-map%20option):

```
ffmpeg -i main.m4v -i commentary.m4v -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a final.m4v
```

With `-map`, the first number in the option refers to the index of the input file (i.e., `0` is the first). The options therefore mean:

- Copy all bitstreams instead of re-encoding
- Take the (first) video stream of the first input
- Take the (first) audio stream of the first input
- Take the (first) audio stream of the second input

All streams that have a `map` option are then copied over.

You could also explicitly refer to a numbered video/audio stream, e.g. `0:a:1`, to refer to the second audio stream in the first file, in case there is any.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not specific to `ffmpeg` you could use this [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317739/how-to-add-an-additional-sound-track-to-an-existing-video)

The [MKVmerge](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html) or [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) tool could append a track on existing video.