# Combining signals into one using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mixing

I have two input sources, each video+audio. I used clapping and superimposed audio frequencies of each to determine that the first leads by x=1.555s. I want to create an output made of the synchronized video and audio of the first and second inputs, respectively.

For trial's sake, I ignored the offset, and tried different variants of the code below, based on a [similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg). I can tell the audio is from the first source because the picture and the sound are in sync.

Evidently, I misinterpreted what the code is doing. Could someone clarify and make a suggestion to achieve the stated goal?

```
$ ffmpeg -i ipad.MOV -i laptop.webm -vcodec copy -acodec copy muxed.MP4
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ipad.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPad mini 4
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 12.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2019-05-06T15:22:15-0400
  Duration: 00:00:15.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8385 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 8279 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'laptop.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.14.1
    creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:16.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:15.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1106 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Output #0, mp4, to 'muxed.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2019-05-06T15:22:15-0400
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPad mini 4
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 12.1
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, q=2-31, 8279 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 19200 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-06T19:22:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  456 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   15539kB time=00:00:15.18 bitrate=8382.5kbits/s speed=32.6x    
video:15350kB audio:175kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.091235%
```

Other variant:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ipad.MOV -i laptop.webm -c:v copy -c:a copy muxed.MP4
```

[image: superimposed audio frequencies]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg has the `-map` option to expressly denote which streams are used for an output. In the absence of `-map`, ffmpeg has an automatic stream selection algorithm, which may not pick the streams you intended.

Use `-map` to pick streams for output:

```
ffmpeg -i ipad.MOV -itsoffset 1.555 -i laptop.webm -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy muxed.MP4
```

See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection

The `itsoffset` delays the 2nd input by 1.555 seconds. Note that your player must support edit lists in MP4 for the delay to be effected. Most modern players do.

Comment: Thanks. It plays fine on VLC, no sound on media player (aac plugin requested).