# Merge audio and video stream in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I saw "https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg" and for a project we need to retrieve video stream (RTMP) from a camera and an icecast audiostream and merge them into a video+audio stream. The original camera audio can be ignored. We'll have to make this available for live viewing, so it's crucial there's not too much delay.

Would `ffmpeg -i https://path/to/videostream -i https://path/to/audiostream.stream -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4` that was suggested in the original thread work?

Comment: The merging should work, but you are writing to a file instead of a stream. Your output seems not to be set right.

Comment: Thanks, something like "-f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234" instead of "-c:a aac output.mp4" ?

Answer (score 0):

Not much info to work with but assuming both input formats are compatible with the output and suitable for your target player/device you can try [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c copy`).

```
ffmpeg -i https://path/to/videostream -i https://path/to/audiostream.stream -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -f flv rtp://output
```

`-map` option is used so it knows which streams you want. Otherwise it may choose the unwanted audio from `https://path/to/videostream`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).