# Uniting various mp4 with various mp3 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I have 50 parts of mp3 audio files and 50 parts of mp4 video files (without audio) files, which I want to unite into one video.
I tried uniting the audio files into one file, then uniting the videos into one file, and eventually unting it all to one video with the following command. I used this [How to merge audio and video file in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg).

`ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i video_list.txt -c:v video.mp4`

`ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i audio_list.txt -c:a audio.mp3`

`ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac final.mkv`

All tryings led to the video being played before the audio in final.mkv (audio delayed).

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Make sure all inputs have the same attributes for proper concatentation.

Comment: How should I check it? And if they don't have the same attributes, how should I still concat them?
I do think I found that the audio is a bit longer, thus I tried to trim each audio part to the exact length of each video part using:



`ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -ss  0 -t  10.011 -c new_0.mp3`



That didn't help. It makes me think that maybe the merge between the final audio and the final video is made in a wrong way.

Comment: 1) You can compare with `ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3`, etc & `ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4`, etc. It will print the details on each input. 2) If they don't match then use various filters to make them match. Many, many concat example on this site and [so] doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I succeeded by uniting each video with the suitable audio with the `-shortest` ffmpeg option. That's made ffmpeg stop encoding once one file ends.
Then I united all the videos that were created together.
Thanks for the help.