# How to merge audio and video streams with different lengths trimming audio to fit video using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, merge

So this always worked before.

I have a video file, lets call it `1.mp4`
I have an audio file that plays, lets call it `2.mp3`

As per this solution, [Merging video and audio, with audio re-encoding](https://superuser.com/a/277667/), I try to merge them using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

`1.mp4` has a shorter length than `2.mp3`, so I want the audio to cut off at the end of the video clip.

The result file `output.mp4` has no sound.

Additionally, the audio stream does show up in VLC when I play it. It shows as an audio track titled `simple_aac`.

I don't tend to lean towards believing VLC didn't work, as it has been a pretty stable option for playing otherwise unplayable video and audio on Linux since forever.

Comment: Hi, where is the command that you're using?

Comment: in the other document. but i'll add it.

Answer (score -1):

If the video is shorter than audio or vice versa and you need to cutoff whichever's the shortest then you might want to use `-shortest` flag

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: this is interesting. so the audio clip plays on vlc. the output file pipes out some errors. ffmpeg doesn't appear to be working as it should. wonder how this might happen. audio stream exists. tried playing it on mplayer as an alternative same problem, no sound.

Comment: can you share link to your your input file and the FFmpeg command you're running?