# possible ffmpeg processing error, audio file is longer than muxed video file, --shortest flag does not appear to work, audio does not play

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

See the question asked here.

[How to merge audio and video streams with different lengths trimming audio to fit video using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1782651/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-streams-with-different-lengths-trimming-audio-to-fi)

ffmpeg is creating output, the audio file itself plays, the video itself plays.

but the output file has no sound. ffmpeg is not throwing any errors.

neither vlc or mplayer two of the most complete video players in Linux are producing sound from the output.mp4

both however are creating some interesting output.

on vlc the following is being outputted:

[00

```
007f12500065a0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.16.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib64/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f12500065a0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f12500065a0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.208.0 (API v208)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007f12500065a0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.208.0 (API v208)
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f126cdf32c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce10040] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f126ce2cdc0] no frame!
```

On Mplayer the following is being outputted:

```
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
[aac @ 0x7fb5c71d39e0]Multiple frames in a packet.
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 2.3 kbit/0.07% (ratio: 284->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
[aac @ 0x7fb5c71d39e0]channel element 0.0 duplicate
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [xv] 1092x614 => 1092x614 Planar YV12 
A:  10.4 V:  10.4 A-V:  0.000 ct: -0.021   0/  0 12%  2%  0.9% 1 0              

Exiting... (Quit)
```

None of the errors relate to audio.
Libplacebo and libva are video rendering apparently.

In Mplayer the stream is being loaded.

What could cause ffmpeg to not mux the streams properly ?

bear in mind the stream lengths are different. the audio is about a minute longer than the video.

Comment: What ffmpeg command are you using to combine the two?

Comment: see the link included.

Comment: Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041061/mix-audio-video-of-different-lengths-with-ffmpeg. As pointed out in the  solution, if the video file also has and audio file, you will need to map the two audio streams (first from the mp4 and second from the mp3)